# Creating navigational pages with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I actually didn't really know how to phrase the question title, but here is the description. Suppose I'm using jQuery to show/hide `ul`s that are stacked on top of each other (absolutely positioned). For example:

```
<ul id="one">
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="two">
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah2</li>
</ul>
```

I have a controller button, that when pressed, simply changes the z-index of these `ul`s. The controller button is literally just:

```
<a href="#" id="mybutton">My button</a>
```

With jQuery code that does: (I'm using the jQuery cycle plugin)

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() { 
  // check which ul is currently shown
  // change z-index, so that the next ul is to be shown
});
```

**THE QUESTION:**

In my site, I have several pages that I would like to point to the *second* `ul`, so that when clicked, it'll bring them to the page with all of the `ul`s, but only the *second* one will be shown. It would be the same if the person went to the page, had the default first `ul` shown, and then clicked "next" to proceed to the next `ul`. I am simply wondering if it's possible to avoid pressing "next", and just bring the user directly to the page and have the second `ul` shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the hash-tag from the URL. You can then write an if statement like this:

```
 if(location.hash === "#2"){
     $("#one").hide();
 }else{
     $("#two").hide();
 }
```

Or directly as a copy and paste example:

```
<html>
<script src="http:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    if(location.hash === "#2"){
        $("#one").hide();
    }else{
        $("#two").hide();
    }
    $('#mybutton').click(function(e) { 
        $("ul").toggle(); //quick n dirty! only works with 2 lists :)
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<a href="#" id="mybutton">My button</a>

<ul id="one">
  <li>First Item!</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="two">
  <li>Second Item!</li>
  <li>blah</li>
  <li>blah2</li>
</ul>

<a href="#2">To second page (you might have to refresh, notice the #2 at the end of the url!)</a>
​</body>
</html>
```

Also notice I've inserted a `e.preventDefault();` at `#mybutton`'s click listener to prevent the URL changing back on clicking.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, perhaps you can accomplish this via a page wrap with a unique id per page?  You can swap the id out with JS or server side logic, depending on what you're trying to do.

```
<div id="page-one">
    <ul id="one">
      <li>blah</li>
      <li>blah2</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="two">
      <li>blah</li>
      <li>blah2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then your css will be `#page-one #one { display:block }; #page-two #one { display : none };` etc.

Comment: How would I then navigate to the page and have #page-two display block?

Comment: With jQuery you can just do `$('body').attr('id', 'page-two');` or you could actually reload the page and handle the wrap id change via different HTML or by switching out the value of a server side var.

Comment: I mean, I understand what you're saying, I'm just still a little unsure of how to handle the situation... Suppose all of these `ul`s are located on page1.html, and you're located on page-x.html. If you were to just go to page1.html, the first div would be shown by default. Now you're on page-x.html, and there's a link that wants to bring you to page1.html, although have the **second** div rather than the first be shown. Maybe the link can direct to page1.html/#second or soemthing, and that would invoke the JS to "click" the next button?

Comment: Yep, you could use the hash (see yoshi's example below). From my perspective it sounds like you are moving towards UX misery (unclear statefulness...what if I as a user *want* to see `<ul>` #1?)...but that would work.